# Measurement of output impedance (ro) of a modified wilson current mirror

Tags: impedance, current-mirror

How do I measure the **small signal output impedance (ro)** of a modified wilson current mirror?

example Q4:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a sophisticated Test Engineer's approach?  Do you have some acceptance criteria? or just idle curiosity?

Comment: At this point just doing some side research for a project

Comment: If you apply a square wave to  DC  at V1  with  a current sense resistor of suitable value, what do you expect for \$R_O = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}=10^7?, 10^{10}?\$?

Comment: I found at gain of 6.3G ohm at 1 Hz, however, it gradually decreases with frequency. I'm not sure why the resistance decreases as the frequency increases.

Comment: What do you expect Coss to be? 1pF? 100pF?

Comment: I models have Cjo=46.3p, so i guess that is the cause :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$R_O = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}\$

In other words, vary the output voltage and measure the corresponding change in current.

If you're asking something more subtle than that, please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Same  answer. Apply an AC voltage and measure the AC current. You can make it as large or small as you like. You can even vary the frequency.

Comment: where is the ideal place to place the AC source?

Comment: In series with V1.

Comment: I found at resistance of 6.3G at 1 Hz